# touchup inside is not working on UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xib

I am developing an iPhone application in Xcode 7.2 **without storyboard.**

Here is my first screen.

I have taken one UIButton, connected it to the method.

But my method is not getting called.

[image]

Below is my code for AppDelegate.

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc]
                           initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    //[self.window addSubview:self.viewController.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

My button click event:

```
- (IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender
{
  NSLog(@"Hello world");
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code which creates the button

Comment: I am dragging connection from my button to code, with touch up inside.

Comment: Please post that code which is not working

Comment: - (IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender{
    
    
    NSLog(@"Hello world");
}

Comment: Right click on the login button and take a screen show , need to see if its connected to fileowner properly.

Answer (score 2):

create selector for UIButton

```
[button addTarget:self 
       action:@selector(buttonAction:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and implement inside method

```
-(void)buttonAction:(id)sender  
{//implement code here  }
```

this is example all code of UIButton from Programmagically(Not use Storyboard)

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self 
  action:@selector(buttonAction:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"LogIn" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 100, 50, 200);
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: Able to call with this. But when I take the button from XIB. Things are not working...

Comment: With XIB only is a easiest way so.

Comment: this link may help you http://rshankar.com/different-ways-to-connect-ibaction-to-uibutton/